# Creating project settings for GeoIP2 in Django

Tags: python, django, geolocation, django-contrib

I'm trying to play around with GeoIP2 for Django, which require you to set the path to your country and city datasets in a `GEOIP_PATH` setting. My issue is that I don't know where I'm supposed to put this setting so that something like the Python shell can see it.

I assume it would go in `settings.py`, but I'm unsure as to the syntax for this particular module, and the Django documentation is absolute rubbish regarding this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're correct that it should be placed inside the `settings.py` file in Django. You should be able to find this file somewhere in your Django project/app. You then place the following in that file:

```
GEOIP_PATH = '/path/to/your/geoip/datafiles'
```

GEOIP willl then be able to locate the files it requires for usage in the application.

### Edit

---

If you want to try GeoIP2 for Django via a python shell you will have to follow the following steps (please note I'm using Windows for this answer, but it should be the same for linux based operating systems):

*Note*: If you already have a Django project set up you can start at step 10.

1. Make sure you have Python installed (I'm using Python 3.5.1 for this answer), inlucding `pip`.
2. Install virtualenvwrapper: `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win` (or `pip install virtualenvwrapper` for non-windows install)
3. Make a virtual environment for your project: `mkvirtualenv GeoIP`
4. Install Django for this project: `pip install django`
5. To check the installation succeeded execute `django-admin --version`, this should show you the version of the Django installtion, which is `1.9.1` for me. If you do not see this, make sure your python installation is correct.
6. Create a directory where you want your projects to be saved. In my case I made a directory called Django: `mkdir Django`
7. Move to this directory: `cd Django`
8. Create a Django project: `django-admin startproject geoip_test`
9. Move to the new directory Django created for you: `cd geoip_test`
10. Install geoip2: `pip install geoip2`
11. Create a directory to store the [required datasets](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/). Please note that these have to be unzipped: `mkdir geoip`. Place the files you downloaded and unzipped in this directory.
12. Start a Django Python shell: `python manage.py shell`
13. Import GeoIP2: `>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2`
14. Create a `GeoIP2` object by instantiating a class with a path to the location of the files you downloaded: `>>> g = GeoIP2('geoip')`
15. Test that everything works: `>>> g.country('google.com')`
    `{'country_code': 'US', 'country_name': 'United States'}`

Comment: Does this include it being findable in the shell as well? Because I just get a "badly configured" error, even setting the path in that way.

Comment: @BHouwens What do you mean? Are you trying to run a file from the shell or are you using python within a shell to try and execute some commands?

Comment: I'm trying to test it in a python shell

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

**Simple steps I found**

1. Pip install geoip2
2. Sign Up at [geoip2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU04T.jpg)
3. Download GeoIP2 and GeoIP Legacy Databases gzip file,
   [page should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMNNL.jpg)
4. Unzip the file in the root of your Django project folder by running `tar -xzf zip_file_name.tar.gz` in your console
5. In your `views.py` for whichever app you need it for, implement like below

.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
def index(request):
 g = GeoIP2('GeoLite2-Country_20223519') #Enter folder name
 country_code = g.country_code('15.194.1.177') #Enter IP address
```